# Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable

Tags: php, symfony-3.3

I'm doing an application where users can add contacts. At the moment I do not have users yet. And I have error when I switching to the person adding form, who previusly worked.

When I remove or comment detailsAction and indexAction, the form works, when I restore the 2 action back again the form does not work.

Error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable.

My controller looks like :

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $entityManager= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $personaldatas = $entityManager->getRepository(Personaldata::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render("Main/index.html.twig",["personaldatas" => $personaldatas]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="details")
 *
 * @param $id
 */
public function detailsAction($id)
{
    $entityManager= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $personaldata = $entityManager->getRepository(Personaldata::class)->findOneBy(["id"=> $id]);
    return $this->render("Main/details.html.twig",["personaldata" => $personaldata]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/add", name="add")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function AddAction(Request $request)
{
    $personaldata = new Personaldata();



    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($personaldata)
        ->add("name", TextType::class)
        ->add("surname", TextType::class)
        ->add("email", TextType::class)
        ->add("phonenumber",TextType::class)
        ->add("dateofbirth",DateType::class)
        ->add("submit",SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $personaldata
        ->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime())
        ->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

    if($request->isMethod("post"))
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $personaldata = $form->getData();

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($personaldata);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute("index");
    }

    return $this->render("Main/add.html.twig",["form" => $form->createView()]);
}
```

my view looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
{{ personaldata.name }}
{{ personaldata.surname }}
{{ personaldata.dateofbirth}}
{{ personaldata.phonenumber}}
{{ personaldata.email }}
{% endblock %}
```

Anyone have an idea what a mistake can be?

ERROR:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable
Twig_Error_Runtime
in app\Resources\views\Main\details.html.twig (line 5)
{% extends "base.html.twig" %} {% block body %}     {{ personaldata.name }}     
{{ personaldata.surname }}     {{ personaldata.dateofbirth}}     {{ 
personaldata.phonenumber}}     {{ personaldata.email }}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You mention you have no users, so `$personaldata` in `detailsAction()` will be `null` which is why you can't access that object's `name` property (or any of them for that matter).

Comment: This application is a phone book pattern. Later, users will be able to add new people to the book, but now I'm doing it. Do you understand now?

Comment: I see, I thought you meant you had no records in the database yet. The error is pretty clear though, `$personaldata` is `null`, because there is no record found (probably). Are you sure the `id` specified actually exists in the database? To avoid this you can check if `$personaldata` is `null` in your action and render a "Data not found" view in that case.

Comment: The database contains records, in the index view they display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there a defined data to avoid such an errors.

within your PHP side, make sure that there are an actual retrieved data from your repository

```
public function detailsAction($id)
{
    $entityManager= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $personaldata = $entityManager->getRepository(Personaldata::class)->findOneBy(["id"=> $id]);

    if (count($personaldata) == 0) {
        $personaldata = null;
    }

    return $this->render("Main/details.html.twig",["personaldata" => $personaldata]);
}
```

and from your twig file, you can use [defined](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html) function

```
{% if personaldata is defined %}
{{ personaldata.name }}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Details wiew and index work perfectly, display records from the database. But When i Add detailsaction - my form has stopped working. When I remove details actions from the controller, the form works again. The error message from the topic I get when going to route: localhost / add